# MySQL Query to get the record for a specific date

Tags: mysql

I have the following table named `staff_status` with structure and records:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| id (INT) | status (VARCHAR) | status_date (DATE) |
----------------------------------------------------
|   1      |     Working      |    2009-05-03      |
|   2      |     Working      |    2009-07-21      |
|   1      |     Leave        |    2010-02-01      |
|   1      |     Working      |    2010-02-15      |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to query this to get the `status` of the staff on a specific date. Example: status of `id = 1` on `2010-02-10` should return `Leave` while on `2010-03-01` should return `Working`

What I have tried without success:

`SELECT t1.status FROM staff_status t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM staff_status WHERE id = 1 AND status_date < '2010-02-10') t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.status_date < t2.status_date);`

Comment: Updated with the attempted query

Comment: Why are you even joining if all you want is the status when you know both the status_date and the id?

Comment: NewInTheBusiness is right, your query seems to differ from the title of your question. All you would need to do is `SELECT status FROM staff_status WHERE id=1 AND date='2010-02-10'`.

Comment: @Derek I now agree with NewInTheBusiness and like astander approach but your query will never work because such a record doesn't exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
SELECT  s.*
FROM    staff_status s INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id,
                    MAX(status_date) status_date
            FROM    staff_status
            WHERE   status_date < '2010-02-10'
            AND     id = 1
        ) m ON  s.id = m.id
            AND s.status_date = m.status_date
```

Additionaly you could try an ORDER BY status_date DESC LIMIT 1

from [13.2.8. SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    staff_status
WHERE   id = 1
AND     status_date < '2010-02-10'
ORDER BY    status_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I like the approach. Which of these two should be better performance vice. I guess the second one?

Comment: That might depend on the indexes on the table.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need the MAX() of the dates per id:

```
SELECT id, MAX(status_date)
FROM staff_status
WHERE status_date < "2010-02-10" GROUP BY id
```

...but MySQL doesn't guarantee that the status will be from the row of the `MAX(status_date)` (in fact, this is almost never the case). So you'll have to take the information you found above, and pull out those records from the original table, matching on `id` and `status_date`:

```
SELECT id, status
FROM staff_status
WHERE
    (id, status_date)
    IN
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(status_date)
        FROM staff_status
        WHERE status_date < "2010-02-10" GROUP BY id
    );
```

This generates a list of `id`s and `status`es for the most recent date found before `2010-02-10`:

```
+------+---------+
| id   | status  |
+------+---------+
|    2 | Working |
|    1 | Leave   |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select status 
from staff_status 
where status_date<='2010-03-01'
and id=1
order by status_date desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar: Sorry I missed while tying

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT status 
               FROM staff_status 
               WHERE id = 1 AND
                     status_date = '2010-02-10'), 
               "Leave") AS status;
```

Comment: If the record is not present in table then you will get Leave as an output for that day.

Answer (score 0):

Surely simply:

```
SELECT status FROM staff_status WHERE status_date = '2010-02-10'
```

Would return you "leave"?

Comment: No because such a record doesn't exists

Comment: Well, with 2010-02-01. Typo on my part.